# recode and target of assignment expands to non-language object

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I am trying to recode a variable.

```
library(car)
```

There is no problem for

```
 bd2011$diag = recode(bd2011$value, 
                 "'7400' <- 'dia1'; else = 'b'")
```

But for

```
bd2011$diag = recode(bd2011$value,
                 " c('7400','7401') <- 'dia1'; else = 'b'")
```

will generate

```
 Error in c("7400", "7401") <- "dia1" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

What is the problem? How to correct?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be single quoting the LHS expressions (unless they are character values) and you should not be using `"<-"`. The value pairs are supposed to be delivered as:

```
c(7,8,9)='high'
```

You might have gotten away with it for a single vector to single item assignment, but with this you are trying to make an assignment from one item to two character values:

```
c('7400','7401') <- 'dia1'
```

The `recode` function is actually making the assignment in the other direction, so using `"<-"` is really confusing as well as incorrect syntax.

You can see why problems will develop by looking at the code that loops over the "recode.list":

```
for (term in recode.list) {
    if (0 < length(grep(":", term))) {...}
    else if (0 < length(grep("^else=", squeezeBlanks(term)))) { ...}
    else {...}
```

Notice: no consideration of the possibility that someone would use `"<-"` or `"->"`.

Then this is what is in the last else-consequent (which would ignore the "<-"):

```
        set <- eval(parse(text = strsplit(term, "=")[[1]][1]))
        target <- eval(parse(text = strsplit(term, "=")[[1]][2]))
        for (val in set) {
            if (is.na(val)) 
              result[is.na(var)] <- target
            else result[var == val] <- target
```

So it should be easy to see that the LHS is being evaluated and assigned to the "target" which comes from the RHS. So if there were a direction to use for assignment, it would have been `"--->"`.

Comment: Thanks.  I took off the quote and there is no error.  But the value is chr.  > str(bd2011)
'data.frame': 1523420 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ data.yr               : chr  "2011" "2011" "2011" "2011" ...
 $ hospital.id           : chr  "0622" "0622" "0622" "0622" ...
 $ patient.ctrl.num      : chr  "1564036" "1564127" "1564182" "1564215" ...
 $ medical.health.rec.num: chr  "007054047" "007054055" "007054059" "007054061" ...
 $ variable              : Factor w/ 19 levels "diagnosis1","diagnosis2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value                 : chr  "V3000" "V3000" "V3000" "V3000" ...

Comment: That comment is pretty useless. Please delete it and edit your Q to have formatted material that makes a reproducible example.